# How to find out installed version of APR?

Tags: apache-2.2

I need to find out, which version of the Apache Portable Runtime is installed on a specific server.

So how can I do this without access to the log files?

Answer (score 7):

Write one line of C :

```
# cat apr.c
int main(void) {
        printf("%s\n",apr_version_string());
}
```

Compile (find the good path to your libapr)

```
# gcc -o apr apr.c /usr/pkg/lib/libapr-1.a
```

execute

```
# ./apr
1.3.3
```

PS: to find libapr you can try

```
ls /usr/lib/libapr*; ls /usr/local/lib/libapr*;ls /lib/libapr*;locate libapr; ...
```

or run ldd over httpd as david says if you want to find the version used by apache

Comment: This doesn't work because the HTTP server doesn't have `gcc`. David's method doesn't work either. Jump straight to [Ken's answer](http://serverfault.com/a/522735/87017).

Comment: @Pacerier the question is "which version of the Apache Portable Runtime is installed" not which APR version is linked to http binary. So, no, Ken answer doesn't answer to Arno question but to "Which version of the Apache Portable Runtime is used by my httpd". Note that APR linked to httpd can be static, so the lib installed on the server might be different that the one used by httpd...

Comment: He tagged the question as apache2.2, so obviously he wants the APR used in apache..............

Answer (score 3):

You don't provide much information, but there are several methods you could try.

1. Ask your package manager. This assumes that you have a system wide libapr installed via your package management system. Debian would be `dpkg -l "*apr*"`. RPM would be  something like `rpm -qa | grep -i apr`.
2. Of course, you might have installed it from source, in which case the library might have the version number encoded in the file name. Run `locate libapr` and it should show something like "/usr/lib/libapr-1.2.3.so"
3. Maybe that didn't find it. Try `ldd /usr/sbin/httpd` (or what ever your APR using binary is) and you'll see what library file your binary will use. This should also show the version number, or will show the location of a symlink to the file with a version number in the name.
4. Finally, it's possible that your binary has APR statically linked in. You can tell if ldd above didn't have APR in the list. You might be able to get a version number by running `strings /usr/sbin/httpd` and looking through for a version number that looks likely. You could also do this if you don't have a .so file with the version number encoded into it.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ find / -name *apr* 2>/dev/null 1>/tmp/apr-findings
$ less /tmp/apr-findings
```

This helped me, because it was so bad documented. I don't know any nicer solution.
If you find a file named `libapr*.la` and you cannot figure out its version number, look into it.
In my case it's something like this:

```
# Version information for libapr-0.
current=9
age=9
revision=4
```

Comment: How to do this on Windows? I can only find `libapr*.dll`, `libapr*.exp`, and `libapr*.lib` and the contents don't show the version information as stated.  Grepping "version" on `libapr-1.dll` shows something like: ............................._apr_uid_compare@8 _apr_uid_current@12 _apr_uid_get@16 _apr_uid_homepath_get@12 _apr_uid_name_get@12 _apr_version@4 _apr_version_string@0 _apr_vformatter@16 _apr_vsnprintf@16.........................................

Answer (score 2):

On windows platform, check this file on apache bin folder: `apr-1-config.pl`

Specifically, the apr version string is stored at this line: `my ${APR_DOTTED_VERSION} = q[1.4.5];`

So, 1.4.5 is your current apr version

Comment: There is no such file `apr-1-config.pl`. The only `pl` I see is `dbmmanage.pl`. Which version are you using? Mine is httpd-2.2.29-win32-ssl_0.9.8-VC9

Answer (score 2):

If you're just trying to find out what version is linked with Apache,
/usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd -V
will tell you.

Comment: How did you find this solution?